# How to use Styled Google maps?

Tags: html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am very new to using Google Maps API and I can't get it to work.

I want a effect like this http://labfiftyfive.com/ about near the bottom they have a map, which is red with a maker. This is the effect I want.

I have gone into the code and got what they are using like the Google API https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false and then the Jscript (bellow), I have then put this into my site, but with no success.

```
var MY_MAPTYPE_ID = 'lab55';
var map;
var theLab = new google.maps.LatLng(-32.055658, 115.747989);

    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 15,
        center: theLab,
  disableDefaultUI: true,
  zoomControl: true,
  scrollwheel: false,
        mapTypeControlOptions: {
            mapTypeIds: [google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, MY_MAPTYPE_ID]
        },
        mapTypeId: MY_MAPTYPE_ID
    };

    var stylez = [
        {
            featureType: 'all',
            elementType: 'all',
            stylers: [
                { hue: '#C1272D' },
                { saturation: 40 },
                { lightness: 40 }
            ]
        }
    ];

    var image = 'img/marker.png';

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('google-maps'), mapOptions);

    map.setOptions({styles: stylez});

    var lab55MapType = new google.maps.StyledMapType(stylez);

map.mapTypes.set(MY_MAPTYPE_ID, lab55MapType);

var markerIcon = new google.maps.MarkerImage(
  image,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  new google.maps.Size(25, 34)
);
    var labMarker = new google.maps.Marker({ 
    position: theLab,
    map: map,
    icon: markerIcon
});

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: "26/36 South Tce<br />Fremantle, 6160"
});
google.maps.event.addListener(labMarker, 'click', function() {
  infowindow.open(map,labMarker);
});
```

I have gone through all the documentation on Google with no success.

So my question is really, does anyone know of any Google tutorials to do this? or and tips which might help?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Can you define `no success`. Any errors? What's not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just using that code (changing the element ID to the one I used in the HTML) [works for me](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_SO_simpleMap_styledMap_lab55.html).  My guess is you have a problem elsewhere in your code (like the map div size is zero).